# Obtener id de usuario logueado

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando obtener el `id` del usuario logueado dentro de una función para poder crear un `query` (no se si de la manera en que lo muestro esta correcto).

Lo que llevo hasta ahora es esto:

```
function obtener_notificaciones($conexion, $us){
    $notu = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postula WHERE du_id = $us AND seen = 0");
    $notu = $resultado->fetchAll();
    return ($notu);
    print_r($notu);
}
```

Tengo otra función para saber si hay una sesión iniciada el cual es el siguiente:

```
   function comprobarSession(){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('Location: ' .  RUTA . '/login.php');
    }
    else {
        $us = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    }
}
```

Lo que también quiero en caso de que mi función sea la correcta, es imprimir el resultado de `$notu` dentro de un `div`

```
<li><a href="notificaciones.html"> Notificaciones (5)</a></li>
```

Para que pueda sustituir el `(5)`por el `count` del `query`

Donde quiero mostrar el `count` es en `lateral.php`en el cual solo tengo etiquetas HTML:

```
<div class="block-section text-center ">
  <img src="images/<?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][14])  ?>" class="img-rounded" alt="">
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
  <h4><a href="perfil.php"><?php echo($_SESSION['usuario'][3])  ?></a></h4>
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="mensajes.php"> Mensajes </a></li>
    <li><a href="notificaciones.html"> Notificaciones (5)</a></li>
    <li><a href="cambio.php"> Cambiar contraseña</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="white-space-20"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
<!-- Block side right -->
```

En las etiquetas `PHP` lo que hago es llamar el arreglo de `$_SESSION` e imprimir los valores del arreglo como se puede observar, así que con la función creada anteriormente quiero cambiar el `(5)` por el resultado de la función que en este caso si no me equivoco seria `$count`

Comment: puedes mostrar por favor donde asignas un valor a esta sesion  `$_SESSION['usuario']`

Comment: @andrezi listo permiteme editar mi pregunta, ya que mi duda ha cambiado:)

Comment: `function obtener_notificaciones($conexion){
$us = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $notu = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postula WHERE du_id = $us AND seen = 0");
    $notu = $resultado->fetchAll();
    return ($notu);
    print_r($notu);
}`

Comment: @andrezi muchas gracias por la correccion, aunque ahora mi otra duda sabes como se haria?

Comment: puedes crear una variable de session, llamada por ejemplo totalNotificaciones y en la parte que necesites mostrar su valor llamas a esa variable, esa variable la asignarias en el metodo obtener_notificaciones.
`<li><a href="notificaciones.html"> Notificaciones ($_SESSION['totalNotificaciones'])</a></li>`

Comment: @andrezi no me quedo muy claro, digo, para que crear una variable de session si estoy haciendo la funcion con el proposito de obtener la "notificacion"

Comment: disculpa, tienes razón estoy suponiendo un escenario, pero en realidad no se que escenario tienes.
Me puedes aclarar un poco mas, como estas trabajando, si tienes una plantilla HTML la cual procesas con PHP y llenas todos los valores después de obtenerlos de la base de datos, o simplemente embebes código PHP en el HTML o si lo realizas de otra forma, cual seria ?.
Y respondiendo a tu pregunta, el escenario que tenia en mi mente era que ejecutabas el php en una pagina distinta a la que mostrabas el html.

Comment: @andrezi oh ya entiendo, si, tengo la plantilla html por aparte de la funcion... es decir, tengo un archivo con nombre `funciones.php` y otro donde se llama `lateral.php` pero en lateral, solo muestro lenguaje `HTML`, permitemelo mostrarlo actualizando la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Tan sencillo como ejecutar antes de sacar el li de las notificaciones la función que has creado y escribir el resultado dentro del html

```
<?php
// Reemplaza $us por el $_SESSION['usuario'][X] que corresponda
$notu = obtener_notificaciones($conexion, $us);
?>

<li><a href="notificaciones.html"> Notificaciones (<?=$notu;?>)</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo modificar tu función `obtener_notificaciones` de la siguiente manera. Observa que como no sé en qué elemento de `$_SESSION['usuario']` almacenas el ID del usuario, asumí que era el primero.

```
function obtener_notificaciones($conexion){
    $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM postula WHERE du_id = ".$_SESSION['usuario'][0]." AND seen = 0");
    $notu = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    return $notu['Total'];
}
```

Y puedes utilizar la función de la siguiente manera

```
<li><a href="notificaciones.html"> Notificaciones (<?php echo obtener_notificaciones($conexion) ?>)</a></li>
```

Comment: Esto, asumiendo que `$_SESSION['usuario']` es del tipo `Array`, en caso de que sea del tipo `int` o `string`, basta con quitar `[0]`, o cambiarlo por el índice que corresponda.

Answer (score -1):

Has una consulta a tu tabla de usuarios y traes los datos que quieras

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname="tubd"', 'user', 'pass');

$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user_name = :usuario'); 
$statement->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));

$resultados = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach ($resultados as $resultado) {
    $id = $resultado['id_usuario'];
    $nombre = $resultado['nombre'];
    $apellido = $resultado['apellido'];
}
```